# PowerBI: Refresh automation with Python

Tags: python, automation, powerbi

I'm trying to automate the refresh function on PowerBI Desktop (For now I don't want to pay for the Pro Licence) with Python but there are so many packages and I'm getting a bit lost. I wanted to use the win32com package first but PowerBI isn't in the application list of the package. I saw that we can use some Microsoft APIs but I don't want to use loads of ressources for this project.

Is it possible to create this automation with Python?
I accept every suggestion possible.

For information I'm using Pycharm Professional with the latest release of Python.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just call the REST API: [Refresh Dataset in Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refresh-dataset-in-group).  This article looks right: [Refresh a Power BI Dataset from Python](https://pbi-guy.com/tag/dataset-refresh/).